# How to get msgs::LogicalCameraImage timestamp?

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I wrote an [urdf](https://github.com/schizzz8/lucrezio_simulation_environments/blob/master/urdf/lucrezio_with_logical.urdf.xacro) for a diff-drive robot with a [logical camera](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=logical_camera_sensor&cat=sensors) sensor.

To publish its messages over ROS I wrote a simple plugin:

```
#include "logical_camera_plugin.h"

using namespace gazebo;
using namespace std;
using namespace ros;

GZ_REGISTER_SENSOR_PLUGIN(LogicalCameraPlugin);

void LogicalCameraPlugin::Load(sensors::SensorPtr _sensor, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf){
  // Get the parent sensor.
  this->parentSensor = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<sensors::LogicalCameraSensor>(_sensor);

  // Make sure the parent sensor is valid.
  if (!this->parentSensor){
    gzerr << "LogicalCameraPlugin requires a LogicalCameraSensor.\n";
    return;
  }

  // Connect to the sensor update event.
  this->updateConnection = this->parentSensor->ConnectUpdated(std::bind(&LogicalCameraPlugin::OnUpdate, this));

  // Make sure the parent sensor is active.
  this->parentSensor->SetActive(true);

  ...

  nh = new ros::NodeHandle("~");
  image_pub = nh->advertise<lucrezio_simulation_environments::LogicalImage>("logical_camera_image", 1, true);
}

void LogicalCameraPlugin::OnUpdate(){
  msgs::LogicalCameraImage logical_image;
  lucrezio_simulation_environments::LogicalImage msg;

  logical_image = this->parentSensor->Image();
  gazebo::rendering::ScenePtr scene = gazebo::rendering::get_scene();
  if (!scene || !scene->Initialized())
    return;

  msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  msg.header.frame_id = "logical_camera_link";
  
  ...
      
  this->image_pub.publish(msg);
}
```

My only concern was:

Is it possible to get from the msgs::LogicalCameraImage a timestamp?

Because, right now, I'm giving ros::Time::now() to the ROS message and I guess this is not the right solution.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19802/how-to-get-msgs::logicalcameraimage-timestamp?/) by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That `LogicalCameraImage` message is not stamped (i.e. it doesn't have a header), so I think it's not possible to know the exact time from the message itself.

I think you're doing the right thing by connecting to the `ConnectUpdated` event. From that callback, *I think* you'll get the correct time for when the last image message was generated with:

`auto lastUpdateTime = this->parentSensor->LastUpdateTime();`

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on 2018-06-22**:
the LogicalCameraPlugin is a `SensorPlugin`, I'm afraid I didn't get what you mean!

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-22**:
Ah sorry, you're right, I woke up too early to watch football. Updating the answer.

**Comment by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on 2018-06-22**:
Thanks, I'll try! "Come on Iceland"!!!!!

**Comment by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on 2018-06-22**:
It doesn't compile because lastUpdateTime is protected within that context

**Comment by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on 2018-06-22**:
my fault, LastUpdateTime should be called!

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-22**:
Oh strange, it should be a public function: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/cc5101392ae32616bf9bf39b6fc051104836aeb1/gazebo/sensors/Sensor.hh?fileviewer=file-view-default#Sensor.hh-129